# Purpose of Some from NSSearchPathDirectory enums

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How I can use enums NSMoviesDirectory or NSMusicDirectory. Documentations says that we can use theirs starting from ios 4 but in my application I can't find any way how to copy files there?
And why Apple have added those enumes if we can't use them?

Answer (score 1):

By default "Movies","Music" and "Pictures" won't be in the Directory.
You have to create the path and place data files.

Eg:`NSMoviesDirectory`

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSMoviesDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSError * error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: documentsDirectory])
{
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
   NSString * resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sleep.mp4"];
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sleep.mp4"] error:&error];

}
else
{
   NSString * resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sleep.mp4"];
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sleep.mp4"] error:&error];

}
```

Comment: nope. Thank you for responce. But it first what I've tried to do. For me it doesn't not working because error: "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 NSFileWriteNoPermissionError". But why apple need us to separate resources? For one of the reasons - its because Apple scan each movie folder in Applications and then generate list of all movies for Videos application. But I can't check this thery because can't create folder and copy there

Answer (score -1):

just write a sample, the music dir(or something else) not exists by default, you should create it codingly.
the sample:

```
- (void)testDir
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSMusicDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *musicDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *defaultFileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if (![defaultFileManager fileExistsAtPath:musicDirectory]) {
        [defaultFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:musicDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:NULL];
    }
    NSString *testDataFilePath = [musicDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.mp3"];
    unsigned int bufferLength = 1024;
    void *buffer = malloc(1024 * sizeof(char));
    NSData *testData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:bufferLength];
    free(buffer); buffer = NULL;
    if (![testData writeToFile:testDataFilePath atomically:NO]) {
        NSLog(@"fail to save data");
    }
    [testData release]; testData = nil;
}
```